# Android layout then scroll programmatically not working

Tags: android, scroll

In my android app, I first programmatically layout a bunch of textViews, in a layout view, then I immediately programmaticallly scroll to a specific textView. Scrolling is not working. I suspect it is because Android has not finished computing the location of things. Scrolling works if I wait between layout and scrolling. I spent the whole day finding a solution. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: actually, android didnt start computing the location of things. just post a Runnable with your scrolling code with some View.post(Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

Default textview can't scroll.
If you want scroolable textview you should use scrollview then add in scrollView,TextView.
Don't add in layout textView. You must add ScrollView.